# Laravel 4 Relationships with name separated by undescore don't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I had a `model` with relationships that have this kind of naming:

```
class PurchaseOrder extends Eloquent implements IModel
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $table = 'purchase_orders';

    // this function has name separated by an _ or underscore
    public function purchased_items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('PurchasedItem');
    }
}
```

and I'm accessing it using:

```
$posted_po = PurchaseOrder::find($po_id);
$purchased_items = $posted_po->purchased_items->all();
```

the code above yields error of

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function all() on a non-object

but somehow changing the name of the relationship solves my problem:

```
public function purchasedItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PurchasedItem');
}

$posted_po = PurchaseOrder::find($po_id);
$purchased_items = $posted_po->purchasedItems->all();
```

Now, my question is, why is that happening? Any reason behind that behavior?

Comment: I suppose it could be because you're calling it as a property, not as a method. Try to add normal braces after the method name so it's like `$posted_po->purchased_items()->all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relation names in Eloquent should be in camelCase. Laravel (mostly) adheres to [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) standards, which states that "Method names MUST be declared in `camelCase`." Nevertheless, a relation with an underscore in it *will* work if called as a method, but will fail when called as a dynamic property, without the trailing `()`.

The reason this happens is because when you call the relation as a property, Eloquent's `__get` method checks to see if that property exists as an attribute or column in your model. Since it doesn't exist, it then converts the name to camelCase and then checks to see if a method exists with that name. So it ends up looking for the method `purchasedItems` in your model.

Comment: Correct, and that means that you **can** call dynamic property like `snake_cased_relation` and it will work as well with `camelCased` method name.